# How different is YUI 3 to YUI 2 to start learning?

Tags: yui

For last two years I have been programming extensively with jQuery and ExtJs. I think now it's time for me to invest some time in learning the impressive YUI library.

In terms of learning from scratch what is advisable? 
I dont plan to use YUI 2 at all in any of my future projects I will use only YUI 3. Is there any paradigm shift in riting code for YUI 2 and YUI 3? or is it only about some cosmetic changes ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

YUI2 and YUI3 are really very different. As different as plain javascript vs jQuery.

Here's an example of setting the background color of all elements of a given class to red to illustrate the difference.

### First in YUI2:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/dom/dom-min.js"></script>
<script>
  var YDom = YAHOO.util.Dom;

  YDom.setStyle(YDom.getElementsByClassName('test'),'background-color','red');

</script>
```

### Now in YUI3:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
  YUI().use('node',function(Y){

    Y.all('.test').setStyle('background-color','red');

  });
</script>
```

Notice the main differences:

- In YUI2 you include the needed modules yourself using the `<script>` tag. In YUI3 you only include one script file with the `<script>` tag and load all the rest using `YUI().use`. In the example above we use the `node` module in YUI3. YUI2 does have a module that can do the auto loading but it is a separate module itself and not built-in to the YAHOO global object.
- YUI2 is traditional imperative programming: `foo(bar())` while YUI3 uses chaining.
- YUI3 forces you to write all YUI related code inside a function therefore running in its own scope and exposes only the `YUI` object to the global scope. This is basically ninja mode in other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. You made many things clear to me. I will be grateful if you can suggest a good starting point for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Learn YUI 3, it is the future of the library. It's also a huge leap forward in terms of usability and flexibility from YUI 2. At this point learning YUI 2 unless you really have to is going to be wasted time.

Comment: That saves me some time and money. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely YUI3... It has great performance enhancements compared to YUI2.

Since you mentioned you have been extensively using jQuery already, this link might help you pick up YUI3 faster----listing the most frequently used YUI3-equivalents of jQuery modules

http://www.jsrosettastone.com/

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 3):

For other people who flock to this page in search of answers, here are a bunch of videos from the YUI blog to get started on YUI3.

[Eric Miraglia’s Welcome to YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=miraglia-yuiconf2009-yui3)

and more videos here - http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/10/27/jquery-and-yui-3-a-tale-of-two-javascript-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

You can find more documentation on YUI3 library here http://yuilibrary.com/

Comment: This should me a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

YUI is a free, open source JavaScript and CSS library for building richly interactive web applications.

YUI is a library of JavaScript utilities and controls for building richly interactive web applications using techniques such as DOM Scripting, DHTML, and Ajax.

1. Fast
2. Modular Architecture / Dependency Management
3. Component Infrastructure
4. Event System
5. DOM Interaction,Ajax,Many Widgets
6. Great Documentation

YUI App Framework

- Is Open Sourced
- Is Developed by Yahoo and the YUI community
- Is based on YUI3
- Is inspired by Backbone.js
- Gives you a basic structure for front end heavy web applications

[More About YUI](http://www.queryhome.com/52432/overview-about-yui)